# How to install OS dependent packages in Zappa (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: django, zappa, python-zappa

I am using `Weasyprint` to convert html to pdf in my code. Everything runs fine locally. `Weasyprint` depends on `wkhtmltopdf`package.

This package needs binaries installed on system with 
`sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf` which is dependancy else I get

> No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"

How can I install this binary required in zappa environment as this is OS depedent package?

Comment: I don't understand: `sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf` should just work and install the dependencies. Are you seeing the error above when running it?

Comment: @dirkgroten I mean how zappa works is it deploys whole django app in AWS lambda function. How can I install something into lamda environment. what I give to zappa is just requirement.txt any idea about doing at OS level not in python virtualenv

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/danielwhatmuff/zappa